# How to get a number from a text file after a specific string in one of the lines somewhere on the line?

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, scripting

I have a text file which contains the following two lines:

```
-host MYPC -param 3 -param2 4
-host MYPC -param3 2 -param4 5
```

I want to get the value corresponding to `-param` which is `3` (`-param 3`) in a Windows batch file.

I tried that with the `findstr` command as shown below:

```
findstr /R "^-param$" > step1_a.txt my_file.txt
```

But it output this:

```
FINDSTR: /c ignored
FINDSTR: /A ignored
FINDSTR: /f ignored
FINDSTR: /f ignored
FINDSTR: /t ignored
FINDSTR: /y ignored
FINDSTR: /a ignored
FINDSTR: /k ignored
```

I think, this is caused by `-` in the string.

How to get the value `3` associated with `-param` in my text file?

Comment: `FINDSTR` is not an inline editor like `SED`.  If you need just the numbers then you need to capture the output of the `FINDSTR` command with a `FOR /F` command.

Comment: @Squashman But how can we extract using `FOR /F` since the position of -param in the text file may change. we have to check first that the number we are reading is followed by the -param.

Comment: By default, the `FOR /F` command will split the output by the space character. You then use the `TOKENS` option to get each number. In your case you would want TOKENS 4 and 6 as those are the 4th and 6th delimited items in the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example code on how to process not really fail safe, but hopefully good enough for your purpose, the lines read from a text file to get the next argument string after a well-known argument string like `-param`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "DataFile=%~dp0my_file.txt"

rem Does the input data file exist?
if exist "%DataFile%" goto ProcessData
rem Input data file not found in directory of the batch file.
echo ERROR: Could not find file: "%DataFile%"
exit /B

:ProcessData
set "ParamValue="
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ("%DataFile%") do for %%J in (%%I) do (
    if not defined ParamValue (
        if /I "%%~J" == "-param" set "ParamValue=1"
    ) else (set "ParamValue=%%~J" & goto HaveValue)
)
rem The parameter of interest was not found at all or there is no value.
echo ERROR: Could not find the parameter with name: "-param"
exit /B

:HaveValue
rem Output the parameter value as an example for further command lines.
set ParamValue

endlocal
```

The outer **FOR** loop reads non-empty lines one after the other from text file and assigns each line completely to the specified loop variable `I`.

The inner **FOR** loop processes the current line similar to how `cmd.exe` processes the argument strings passed to a batch file. All space/tab/comma/semicolon/equal sign/non-breaking space (in OEM encoding) delimited strings are ignored until a string is found which is case-insensitive equal the string `-param`. The next string in the current line is assigned to the environment variable `ParamValue` and the two loops are exited with the command **GOTO** to continue batch file processing on the line below the label `:HaveValue` where the environment variable `ParamValue` can be used for whatever purpose.

This extended version of above gets first the string after `-param` which is in the example `3`. Then the entire text file is searched again for an argument string starting with `-param` and the string appended which was read first from file which is in the example `-param3`. If this string is found, the next string is assigned to environment variable `ParaValue` which is `2` in the example.

```
@echo off
set "DataFile=%~dp0my_file.txt"

rem Does the input data file exist?
if exist "%DataFile%" goto ProcessData
rem Input data file not found in directory of the batch file.
echo ERROR: Could not find file: "%DataFile%"
exit /B

:ProcessData
set "ParamName="
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ("%DataFile%") do for %%J in (%%I) do (
    if not defined ParamName (
        if /I "%%~J" == "-param" set "ParamName=1"
    ) else (set "ParamName=-param%%~J" & goto HaveName)
)
rem The parameter of interest was not found at all or there is no value.
echo ERROR: Could not find the parameter with name: "-param"
exit /B

:HaveName
set "ParamValue="
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ("%DataFile%") do for %%J in (%%I) do (
    if not defined ParamValue (
        if /I "%%~J" == "%ParamName%" set "ParamValue=1"
    ) else (set "ParamValue=%%~J" & goto HaveValue)
)
rem The parameter of interest was not found at all or there is no value.
echo ERROR: Could not find the parameter with name: "%ParamName%"
exit /B

:HaveValue
rem Output the parameter value as an example for further command lines.
set ParamValue

endlocal
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~dp0` ... batch file path ending always with a backslash.
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Answer (score 1):

You used anchors `^` and `$` which mark begining of a line and end of a line (see [findstr docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr)).

Correct pattern would be: `findstr /r /c:"-param [0-9]*"`

I used additional flag `/c`, so you can use spaces inside the pattern and they will not be treated as "or" operator.

Pattern is simple: first match `-param`  literally, then match zero or more digis with `[0-9]*`

Comment: But it is giving the complete line not the number followed by -param.

Comment: @GauravSahu It is not possible to extract part of the string. It always outputs whole line.